# How to read nested object values and it's key from Firestore in android (Java)

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to read values from nested objects along with there keys in android, but i am unable to find any solution according to my requirement. (I am new to firestore and android development)
[image: Firestore-database image]

**I tried foreach loop but it shows error**- foreach not applicable to type 'java.util.Map' :-

```
for(DocumentSnapshot ds: document.getData())
```

**So then i tried this:-**

```
Map<String, Object> myMap = (Map<String, Object>) document.getData();
String name = ""; //don't know how to get key i.e(clamp,gear) as i can't pass all of them.
String url = (String) myMap.get("url");//url returns null
```

**This is my code:-**

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("categoryType").document("Hardware");
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    if (document.exists()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());//see log below
                        Map<String, Object> myMap = (Map<String, Object>) document.getData();
                        String name = "";
                        String url = (String) myMap.get("url");
                        ItemCategory category = new ItemCategory(name,url);
                        itemCategoryList.add(category);
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
                }
                itemCategoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

**Log.d prints this:-**
`{Hammer={url=https://someURL}, Nail={url=https://someURL}, Shovel={url=https://someURL}}`

**So in short what i want is:-**
name = "Hammer"
url = "someUrl",

name = "Nail"
url = "someurl"

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to get the Clamp map, then use that to get its url property.  This is pseudocode, not full code, but illustrates what you need to do.  Generics on maps are missing for brevity:

```
// get the document data map from the snapshot
Map data = snapshot.getData();
// get the Clamp field, which is an object field, so it will arrive as a Map
Map clamp = (Map) data.get("Clamp");
// get the String value of the url property on the object
String url = (String) clamp.get("url");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem with above code is i need to pass field("Clamp") statically which i can't do as there are n numbers of fields. So i there any way i can read those key and then store them in variable and then pass it dynamically like this:- `String name = " "; //it will contain the key which i want to read from documentSnapshot like clmap,hammer` and then pass this variable like this :-  `Map item = (Map) data.get(name);`

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late but helpful for some other.

If you want to get the field names dynamically create an array and add all field names to that array, also when adding new data add it's field name to that array.

Now with this array you can create a for loop to get all fields.